# Await method called twice and then the app crashes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-8.1, async-await

I'm developing a Win 8.1 application with C#.

I wrote a button_click event.

```
private async void btnsignup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (await CheckSignUpInputData())
 {
          if (await CheckExistingEmailAddress(txtregemail.Text))
          {
              //Do something
          }
  }
}

private async Task<bool> CheckSignUpInputData()
{
//Some calculation, if correct return true
}

private async Task <bool> CheckExistingEmailAddress(string newemail)
{
//If correct return true
}
```

After CheckSignUpInputData() finishes, the debugger call btnsignup_Click() again, CheckSignUpData() runs at the second time and after crash.
Visual Studio jumps here:

```
if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)       
global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

in the App.g.ics file.

What could be the problem? Maybe I forgot about something?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: how do you implement your methods (CheckSignUpInputData, CheckExistingEmailAddress)?

Comment: `async` isn't magically causing an error here. If you're seeing an exception, then it's most likely being thrown from one of your `Check*` methods. The exception details will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: You are right! I use Azure Mobile Service and one of the insert.js script fails, that throws an exception. And now I use the PointerPressed event (not the click) and there I can set e.Handled to true. With theese my code works fine! Thank you very much!